# Jquery dependent drop-down menu select

Tags: jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu, phalcon

Sorry for my poor english. I'm unable to make option value selected from jquery dependent drop-down menu. I have three drop menu 1st category, 2nd is sub-category and 3rd is sub sub-category. 2nd and 3rd menu are always disabled by default in entry and update mode. i can make selected in category dropbox which user already selected but unable to make selected in sub-category and sub sub-category menu.below is my complete code:

[image]

[controller]

```
public function productEditAction($id)
{
    $product = Products::findFirstByid($id);

    $this->view->id = $product->id;
    $this->view->setVar('pcid', $product->category_id);
    $this->view->setVar('pscid', $product->subcategory_id);
    $this->view->setVar('psscid', $product->sscid);

    $category = Categories::find();
    $this->view->setVar('categories',$category);
    $this->view->pick("index/entry");

}

public function getSubcategoryAction()
{ 
    $this->view->disable();
    $id = $this->request->getPost('id');
    $data = Subcat::findBycategory_id($id); 
    $resData = array();    
    foreach($data as $result)
    {
        $resData[] = array('id' => $result->id, 'category_id' => $result->category_id, 'subcategory' => $result->subcategory_name);
    }
    echo(json_encode($resData));       
}
public function getsscAction()
{ 
    $this->view->disable();
    $id = $this->request->getPost('id');
    $data = Ssc::findBysubcatid($id);  
    $resData = array();    
    foreach($data as $result)
    {
        $resData[] = array('id' => $result->id, 'subcatid' => $result->subcatid, 'ssctitle' => $result->ssctitle);
    }
    echo(json_encode($resData));       
}
```

[jQuery]

```
//Dependent List Category Action
$("select[name='category']").on("change", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value === '0'){$("select[name='subcategory']").attr("disabled", true); $("select[name='ssc']").attr("disabled", true);}else{$("select[name='subcategory']").attr("disabled", false);} 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/shopping/backend/index/getSubcategory",
        data:'id='+value,       
    }).done(function(response){
        $("#subcategory").find('option').not(":first").remove();    
        $("#ssc").find('option').not(":first").remove();
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        response.forEach(function(value){
            $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.subcategory+'</option>');
        });
    }).fail(function(){
            console.log('error: Please reload page and try again!');
    }).always(function(){
            console.log('Complete:');
    });
});
//Dependent List Sub-Category Action
$("select[name='subcategory']").on('change', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value === '0'){$("select[name='ssc']").attr("disabled", true);}else{$("select[name='ssc']").attr("disabled", false);}    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/shopping/backend/index/getssc",
        data:'id='+value,       
    }).done(function(response){     
            $("#ssc").find('option').not(":first").remove();
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            response.forEach(function(value){               
                $('#ssc').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.ssctitle+'</option>');
            });
    }).fail(function(){
            console.log('error: Please reload page and try again!');
    }).always(function(){
            console.log('Complete:');
    });
});
```

[Form]

```
Category: 
<select name="category">
    <option value="0">Choose Category ...</option>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <option value="{{category.id}}" {% if category.id === pcid %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{category.categoryname}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select><br/>
sub-Category:<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" disabled="disabled"><option value="0">Choose Sub-Category ...</option></select><br/>
Sub-Sub-Category:<select name="ssc" id="ssc" disabled="disabled"><option value="0">Choose Sub-Sub-Category ...</option></select><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing Special you have to do!!

add following lines in your controller:

```
$subcategory = Subcat::findBycategory_id($product->category_id);
$this->view->setVar('subcategories',$subcategory);  

$Sscat = Ssc::findBysubcatid($product->subcategory_id);
$this->view->setVar('ssc',$Sscat);
```

And in your form:

```
sub-Category:
<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="0">Choose Category ...</option>
    {% for subcategory in subcategories %}
        <option value="{{subcategory.id}}" {% if subcategory.id === pscid %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{subcategory.subcategory_name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select><br/>
Sub-Sub-Category:
<select name="ssc" id="ssc" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="0">Choose Category ...</option>
    {% for Sscat in ssc %}
        <option value="{{Sscat.id}}" {% if Sscat.id === psscid %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{Sscat.ssctitle}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select><br/>
```